# Sonar broken after installing python plugin: The plugin python is not supported with Java 1.6.0_29

Tags: java, python, sonarqube

I am using windows and installing the python 1.5 plugin from
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Python+Plugin

Sonar breaks after I install this, the java version that is needed is not even specified. Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube and the latest versions of the plugins all requires java 7 see requirements : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements

No workaround, java 6 is no more supported, so please use at least java 7 (moreover, java 8 is recommended as Java 6 and 7 are now not supported anymore)

Answer (score 2):

According to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements, Sonar is not supported on Java 6 anymore.

> Are there any workarounds for this?

Upgrade your Sonar platform to a more recent version of Java.  Preferably Java 8, because Java 7 has been EOL'd by Oracle.  (You could get away with using Java 7 if your Sonar platform is behind a firewall, but running a Java 7  based service with publicly facing web access is risky.)